# Insert data in column with logged user to check to who has updated/created in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have query:

```
"INSERT INTO mappings (id, service, created_at) 
        VALUES(%s,%s)" % (id, service)
```

Here I want to insert information about logged in user under created_at column value.

Don't want to use date and time.
Can some one please help me on this?

Comment: information about user is what? his id? username?

Comment: Just want to use user name

Comment: could you provide some more code so i can check out how to get the username?

Comment: @Nhor: I don't want to get username.  I want to insert username or name if insert query gets executed. `56` ,'1455','niya'  `34`,`5678`, `Nhor` . something like this

Comment: it's unclear to me which username do you want to insert. where is the desired username coming from? i assume it's not random

Comment: @Nhor : It is not coming from anywhere. I am getting `Id` and `Service` from other queries and inserting in Database with insert query. In insert query I have field /column ,which is `created_at`. In created_at column I would like to insert name of the person who is going to execute this insert query. Because this insert query in python with other code where I am making it like shell scripting. so that other person also can execute and if it gets execute I can capture name of that person and insert.

Comment: so that's not coming from anywhere - it's the user that is executing the query. it he doing this by a request?

Comment: @niya. Read my answer and try to understand it. The idea of the query I have proposed is that you ask the server to accept 3 values to 3 fields: 2 values are parameters that are sent from client application and the third is the result of the function that fetches the name of the user calling the query (who has opened connection). The second way I have shown you is a trigger that fires before insert. It sets (assignes) to the created_at field of the NEW (it's a keyword) record the result of the function that fetches the name of the user who is trying to insert this record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following function to get the user name.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GETUSERNAME`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GETUSERNAME`() RETURNS char(16) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1));
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

This function parses USER() result and separates user name from user host. Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1)` if you wish to get the host. And then insert a record

```
INSERT INTO `mappings` (`id`, `service`, `created_at`) 
VALUES(:param1, :param2, GETUSERNAME());
```

or a copy of your code:

```
"INSERT INTO mappings (id, service, created_at) 
        VALUES(%s,%s,GETUSERNAME())" % (id, service)
```

You can also do it in a before insert trigger. That will be

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `trbinsertmappings` BEFORE INSERT ON `mappings` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.created_at=GETUSERNAME();
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

If you need an id then I use the alike function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GETUSERID`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GETUSERID`() RETURNS int(10)
BEGIN
  DECLARE   id_no INT DEFAULT -1;
  select `id` 
  INTO id_no 
  FROM `tstaff` 
  WHERE `tstaff`.`user_name`=(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1)) 
  LIMIT 1;

  RETURN id_no;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Don't want to get user name. I want to insert username/name who is going to insert value in table.  say : If I execute insert query on my machine it should insert record in created_at column my name and if ABC is executed then ABC name should come in created_at.

Comment: @niya. I have given the exact answer to your question. Read it again I have given you the 2 variants to do it. They both will insert the name of the user who has called the query (established connection session) into your table. In other words different users will insert different rows as their name will be set in the appropriate field.

Comment: @niya I have unscrolled the insert query (the 1st method to do the job requested by you) and trigger creation query (the 2nd method) for easier understanding.

Comment: I have tried answer but it was giving me problem that getusername does not exist. did not dig too much. I will try once again and will let you know in late evening.

Comment: @niya It can give this answer if you have not created the function. Run the first query.

Comment: :Thank you so much. I will try.